# how to make the result from result_lbl from window 1 to window 2?

Tags: tkinter, label

How would I access the output from result_lbl of window 1 to window 2? I had being reading and seems that I need to use "controller" somewhere to link the 2 classes together, but it seems like with "controller" there needs to be a lambda function somewhere, which I thought was a no no. Would someone please help me out.  Thanks.

```
import tkinter as t

def main(): 
    root = t.Tk()
    root.geometry("250x370")
    root.config(background="LightBlue4")
    root.title("print to screen")
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()

class Application:
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.parent=parent

        self.frame_top = t.Frame(self.parent, bg="tan", bd=2,      relief=t.RIDGE)
        self.frame_top.pack(anchor=t.N, fill=t.BOTH, expand=1)

        self.frame_btm = t.Frame(self.parent, bg="plum1", bd=2, relief=t.RIDGE)
        self.frame_btm.pack(anchor=t.S, fill=t.X, expand=0)
```

## ----------------------------------------------------------------

```
        self.labelVariable=t.StringVar()
        self.result_lbl=t.Label(self.frame_top,   font="Helvetica 50 bold italic", textvariable=self.labelVariable)
        self.result_lbl.pack()

        self.entryVariable = t.StringVar()
        self.entry=t.Entry(self.frame_btm, textvariable=self.entryVariable)
        self.entry.bind("<Return>", self.on_button)
        self.entry.pack()


        self.button = t.Button(self.frame_btm, text="print to screen", command=self.on_button)
        self.button.pack()

        self.button_window=t.Button(self.frame_btm, text="2nd", fg="brown",command=self.second_window)
        self.button_window.pack()
```

## ---------------------------------------------

```
    def on_button(self):
        self.labelVariable.set(self.entryVariable.get())
        self.entry.delete(0,"end")


    def second_window(self):
        self.second_window = t.Toplevel(self.parent)
        self.second_window.geometry("250x370")
        self.second_window.title("2nd window")
        self.app = Window_2(self.second_window)

class Window_2:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent

        self.frame= t.Frame(self.parent, bg="tan", bd=2, relief=t.RIDGE)
        self.frame.pack(anchor=t.N, fill=t.BOTH, expand=1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: what are windows 1 and 2 ?

Comment: Window one is the first init and the second window is the second init. I have a botton that says second window. Once i click that the second window pop up. What i am trying to do is display the same output from the main window onto a second window into a monitor. Thanks Bill again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are few things I would like to comment about your program, however, I am going to mention only the things directly related to your actual problem.

## Redesign your program and code less

Better design means less code. On the name of this development *verse*, your second class:

```
class Window_2:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent

        self.frame= t.Frame(self.parent, bg="tan", bd=2, relief=t.RIDGE)
        self.frame.pack(anchor=t.N, fill=t.BOTH, expand=1)
```

is completely useless regarding the goal you want to achieve. All what you would implement in this class, you could do it in `self.second_window` frame which you created using  [`Toplevel()`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/toplevel.html).

So just take the configuration of `Window_2` class and inject it into `self.second_window` toplevel frame. This way you move and keep the design of the first into the later.

```
self.second_window = t.Toplevel(self.parent, bg = 'tan', bd=2,  relief=t.RIDGE)
```

Also, for the sake of code maintenance and scalability,  I would like to suggest you to rename the variable `self.second_window` in `self.second_window()` method to something else, let's say to `self.second_win`. As your code goes longer, this may be a source of confusion or eventually bugs not only for your peers who would work on your code but also for yourself.

## Program re-design benefits

You may guess that the re-design we did above has a direct positive impact to resolve your problem. This is because your second frame (or window as you call it) `self.second_window()` looks now just like a simple method that can now access simply any member of `Application()` class, namely `self.result_lbl`. This way, your problem is already almost solved.

## The trick

The trick to complete the solution of your problem is now to create an other label within what you call *the second window*, let's call it `self.result_lbl_copy` that we need to show in `self.second_wind` then we must set its text to the same text as in `self.result_lbl` using [`cget()`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/universal.html) method.

Which thing is reflected in our code by:

```
self.result_lbl_copy=t.Label(self.second_win,   font="Helvetica 50 bold italic", textvariable=self.labelVariable, text = self.result_lbl.cget('text'))
self.result_lbl_copy.pack()
```

## Full program

Here is the program you can test:

```
'''
Created on Apr 21, 2016

@author: billal begueradj
'''
import tkinter as t

def main(): 
    root = t.Tk()
    root.geometry("250x370")
    root.config(background="LightBlue4")
    root.title("print to screen")
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()

class Application:
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.parent=parent

        self.frame_top = t.Frame(self.parent, bg="tan", bd=2,      relief=t.RIDGE)
        self.frame_top.pack(anchor=t.N, fill=t.BOTH, expand=1)

        self.frame_btm = t.Frame(self.parent, bg="plum1", bd=2, relief=t.RIDGE)
        self.frame_btm.pack(anchor=t.S, fill=t.X, expand=0)
        self.labelVariable=t.StringVar()
        self.result_lbl=t.Label(self.frame_top,   font="Helvetica 50 bold italic", textvariable=self.labelVariable)
        self.result_lbl.pack()

        self.entryVariable = t.StringVar()
        self.entry=t.Entry(self.frame_btm, textvariable=self.entryVariable)
        self.entry.bind("<Return>", self.on_button)
        self.entry.pack()


        self.button = t.Button(self.frame_btm, text="print to screen", command=self.on_button)
        self.button.pack()

        self.button_window=t.Button(self.frame_btm, text="2nd", fg="brown",command=self.second_window)
        self.button_window.pack()

    def on_button(self):
            self.labelVariable.set(self.entryVariable.get())
            self.entry.delete(0,"end")


    def second_window(self):
            self.second_win = t.Toplevel(self.parent, bg = 'tan', bd=2,  relief=t.RIDGE)
            self.second_win.geometry("250x370")
            self.second_win.title("2nd window")
            self.result_lbl_copy=t.Label(self.second_win,   font="Helvetica 50 bold italic", textvariable=self.labelVariable, text = self.result_lbl.cget('text'))
            self.result_lbl_copy.pack()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

## Demo

Here is a screenshot of the running program:

### [image]

## EDIT:

## Solution while keeping the bad design

If you want to keep the previous *bad* design by using `Window_2()` class anyway then the solution does not change that much.

Just before this line:

```
self.app = Window_2(self.second_window)
```

Insert the same two lines I mentioned above for the trick:

```
self.result_lbl_copy=t.Label(self.second_window,   font="Helvetica 50 bold italic", textvariable=self.labelVariable, text = self.result_lbl.cget('text'))
self.result_lbl_copy.pack()
```

## Full program

Here is the full program with your own design:

```
'''
Created on Apr 22, 2016

@author: billal begueradj
'''

import tkinter as t

def main(): 
    root = t.Tk()
    root.geometry("250x370")
    root.config(background="LightBlue4")
    root.title("print to screen")
    app = Application(root)
    root.mainloop()

class Application:
    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.parent=parent

        self.frame_top = t.Frame(self.parent, bg="tan", bd=2,      relief=t.RIDGE)
        self.frame_top.pack(anchor=t.N, fill=t.BOTH, expand=1)

        self.frame_btm = t.Frame(self.parent, bg="plum1", bd=2, relief=t.RIDGE)
        self.frame_btm.pack(anchor=t.S, fill=t.X, expand=0)
        self.labelVariable=t.StringVar()
        self.result_lbl=t.Label(self.frame_top,   font="Helvetica 50 bold italic", textvariable=self.labelVariable)
        self.result_lbl.pack()

        self.entryVariable = t.StringVar()
        self.entry=t.Entry(self.frame_btm, textvariable=self.entryVariable)
        self.entry.bind("<Return>", self.on_button)
        self.entry.pack()


        self.button = t.Button(self.frame_btm, text="print to screen", command=self.on_button)
        self.button.pack()

        self.button_window=t.Button(self.frame_btm, text="2nd", fg="brown",command=self.second_window)
        self.button_window.pack()
    def on_button(self):
           self.labelVariable.set(self.entryVariable.get())
           self.entry.delete(0,"end")


    def second_window(self):
           self.second_window = t.Toplevel(self.parent)
           self.second_window.geometry("250x370")
           self.second_window.title("2nd window")
           self.result_lbl_copy=t.Label(self.second_window,   font="Helvetica 50 bold italic", textvariable=self.labelVariable, text = self.result_lbl.cget('text'))
           self.result_lbl_copy.pack()
           self.app = Window_2(self.second_window)


class Window_2:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent

        self.frame= t.Frame(self.parent, bg="tan", bd=2, relief=t.RIDGE)
        self.frame.pack(anchor=t.N, fill=t.BOTH, expand=1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I tested this program and it leads to the same interface. You can choose between the two solutions, however I recommend you the first one for reasons I mentioned.

## About  `on_button()` method

I want to prevent you from an error that you did not ask but which I discovered in your program: There is a problem with this function:

```
def on_button(self):
       self.labelVariable.set(self.entryVariable.get())
       self.entry.delete(0,"end")
```

Change its definition to:

```
 def on_button(self,something):
```

`something` is just an argument which you can call with any name such as `begueradj`. If you don't understand why, let me know. But first execute your program by running <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Hi Billal, thanks again for the insight.  The 2nd class idea was something that I saw from another post and I thought could apply to my case and since I am an amateur, I wanted to try it.  Your first version is good, I tried it.

Comment: thanks for the info on the on_button. I think you are referring to another code that I need to add at the end of the program due to an quirkiness of python?  I got a book on tkinter and I think that's what they are saying.  About the negative review, I don't know what happened.  I wanted to give you positive feedback, but my profile doesn't allow me to add them due to the new profile.@ Billal BEGUERADJ

Comment: I edited my answer and gave you a solution without any modification to your code (keeping the class `Window_2`). @fishtang

Comment: Is that with the check to accept the answer?@billal BEGUERADJ

Comment: i did it. Please understand i didnt do anything about the negative 1. As always  i appriciate all your help. @Billal BEGUERADJ

Comment: you need to have 125 reputation to be able to downvote, so i know it is not you, do not worry :) @fishtang